Is it idiomatic to say that the presidential candidate is the running mate of the vice-presidential candidate?
The caption provided for this YouTube video says:

Walz, Vance stump for running mates after VP debate

Is it idiomatic to say that the presidential candidate is the "running mate" of the vice-presidential candidate?

This looks like headlinese and is perfectly idiomatic in that context.

While we usually use the term "running mate" to refer to the lower partner of a candidate, there's no reason it can't be generalized.
The word "mate" normally refers to a reciprocal relationship. Friends are mates, and if you're my friend then I'm usually your friend as well. Marriage is also a mating relationship, so the husband wife are each others' mates.
So it will easily be understood if you refer to the presidential candidate as their corresponding VP candidates' running mates.
